# timeout command and pipe - order of precedence

Tags: timeout

I need to test receipt of TCP data. I **may not** use iperf.

The requirements are saying that I should create a TCP server to  which will someone will send random data. I need to count the number of bytes received.

I have been told to use the following:

```
timeout 60 cat < /dev/tcp/IP_addr/port | wc –c > byte_count-n.txt
```

Will this do what they think it will? Will it receive data for 60 seconds and then, when the timeout expires, pipe the received data to `wc`, which will write the total to a disk file?

As a programmer, I would feel happier if it read

```
(timeout 60 cat < /dev/tcp/IP_addr/port) | wc –c > byte_count-n.txt
```

But obviously the shell won’t accept that. Am I correct to be worried?

Note that we are using the Ash shell, but there is some concern that only Bash supports `/dev/tcp`

Comment: This is a re-state of a [previous question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330086/117516), under less meaningful requirements. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note that this answers [an earlier version of the question](/revisions/331362/3) where the command was meant to be a *server*.</sup>

No in `bash` (and `ksh` where that feature comes from), `/dev/tcp/host/port` are virtual files that are meant to be for *client* TCP connections.

The shell will *connect* to host:port, and make that connected socket the fd that is the subject of the redirection. With `<` or `<>`, it's fd 0 (stdin), with `>`, `>>` it's fd 1, but the operators make no difference. In particular it's not because you use `<` that the shell shuts down the sending direction of the socket; stdin will still be connected to a socket which you can both read from and write to.

If you want to listen (be a server) and accept one or more connections, you can't use `/dev/tcp/host/port`.

You'd need to use a dedicated tool like `socat` or `nc`, or a shell with builtin support for that like `zsh` with its `ztcp` builtin.

```
timeout 60 socat -u tcp-listen:12345,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1,fork - | wc -c
```

Will listen on port 12345 on the loopback IPv4 address and accept incoming connections in child processes, write what is received on stdout (here piped to `wc`).

There are several implementations of a tool called `nc` or `netcat` with which you can generally do the same with:

```
timeout 60 nc -l 127.0.0.1 12345 | wc -c
```

Note that it run that command for 60 seconds. That includes the time while it's sitting doing nothing waiting for incoming connections.

If you want the timer to start upon the incoming connection, you could do instead:

```
socat -u tcp-listen:12345,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1 'EXEC:timeout 60 cat' | wc -c
```

Here accepting only one TCP connection (no `fork`) which is then piped to `timeout 60 cat`.

Just to clarify what I think you may be asking in the subject, when you do:

```
 cmd1 | cmd2
```

It's not `cmd1` running and when it's finished, the data is sent to `cmd2`. Instead `cmd1` and `cmd2` are started concurrently (they run in parallel) with a pipe in between them (`cmd1`'s stdout is the writing end of the pipe and cmd2's stdin is the reading end).

In:

```
 timeout 60 nc -l 127.0.0.1 12345 | wc -c
```

You've got `timeout` and `wc` running in parallel. `timeout` starts another process in which it executes `nc` (which will share the same stdout).

After 60 seconds, `timeout` will *kill* that other process. At that point `nc` will exit, but it will have written what it has received from the socket to the pipe (`nc` or `socat` don't buffer their output), so even if `wc` hasn't read it yet, it will be accounted for as `wc` will keep reading until the pipe is empty.

```
(timeout 60 nc ...) | wc –c
```

Would be the same. `(code)` is to start a subshell (a child shell process (in shells other than ksh93) that is evaluating the `code`). But here, since it's part of pipeline, that code has to be in a subshell already (different parts of a pipeline have to run in different processes as they run concurrently).

Comment: A fast and detailed response form someone who's reputation indicates that he knows what he is speaking of.  I will take this answer to management.

Comment: Aaaaargh!! I made a ***big*** mistake. I am suppsed to be a client, not a server. Please accept my apologies. I will update the question. What difference does it make?

Comment: @Mawg, That's now a very different question, so most of my answer is now irrelevant, but then there's probably enough information in here to show you that yes, it should work as expected provided `cat` doesn't buffer its output (the GNU implementation doesn't, you can add the `-u` option for others (ignored by GNU `cat`)).

Comment: My apologies - again :-)  I have accepted you answer and reverted the question to its original, so that the question & answer match